# Nearest neighbour problem (a quite simple one)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have the following traveling salesman problem:

[image]

My answers for these are 98 and 104 but the book's answers are 103 and 110 respectively. Who is right?

[image]

Comment: Upper bound on what?

Comment: The upper weight (maximum weight, or upper limit). It is a traveling salesman problem

Comment: Your attempt would be clearer by telling us the cycles you found.

Comment: The circles on the table show the path that I've found:
AECBDA and ADCBEA

Comment: @saulspatz: the OP means an upper bound on the length of the shortest cycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [nearest neighbour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbour_algorithm) to find a tour starting at A goes like this: 19 to E, 18 to C, 14 to B, 21 to D, and 26 to A, for a total path length of 19+18+14+21+26=98. Thus it looks like the book answer is wrong here.

Using the second distance matrix, you would find: start at A, 17 to D, 18 to C, 22 to B, 31 to E, and 22 to A, for a total of 17+18+22+31+22=110. Looks like here you miscalculated.

Comment: Sorry I mistyped the book's answers. It is as it is now.